# min() max() and sum() functions working on pandas group by object but not mean()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, mean

So basically, I have grouped month columns into quarters like columns 2000-01,2000-02,2000-03 into a single group 2000q1 where q1 means quarter 1 and so on. I have done is for 16 x 12 months and formed 48 quarters.

Now, I wish to get the average value of each row in a group. When I do `grouped.max()`  `grouped.min()` and `grouped.sum()` I get the min , max and sum of each row in each group.(The row indices are the same for each group)

But when I try `grouped.mean()` I get an error saying:

> **No numeric types to aggregate.**

Here is the code that I have written:

```py
def quarter(val):
    month=val[5:]
    if month == "01" or month == "02"or month == "03":
        return val[:4]+"q1"
    elif month == "04"or month == "05"or month == "06":
        return val[:4]+"q2"  
    elif month == "07" or month == "08" or month == "09":
        return val[:4]+"q3"    
    elif month == "10"or month == "11"or month == "12":
        return val[:4]+"q4"  
city.fillna(0,inplace=True)


g=city.groupby(quarter, axis= 1 ).mean()
```

**This is how my grouped data looks like**

[('2000q1',          2000-01    2000-02    2000-03

**0**            0.0        0.0        0.0
**1**       204400.0   207000.0   209800.0
**2**       136800.0   138300.0   140100.0
**3**        52700.0    53100.0    53200.0
**4**       111000.0   111700.0   112800.0
**5**       131700.0   132600.0   133500.0

...

('2000q2',          2000-04    2000-05    2000-06
**0**            0.0        0.0        0.0
**1**       212300.0   214500.0   216600.0
**2**       141900.0   143700.0   145300.0
**3**        53400.0    53700.0    53800.0
**4**       113700.0   114300.0   115100.0
**5**       134100.0   134400.0   134600.0

...

('2002q2',          2002-04    2002-05    2002-06
**0**            0.0        0.0        0.0
**1**       268600.0   272600.0   276900.0
**2**       177800.0   177600.0   177300.0
**3**        60300.0    60700.0    61200.0
**4**       127900.0   128400.0   128800.0
**5**       150400.0   151000.0   151400.0

This is how city looks like
[image]
This is a part of the output I get when I do grouped.max()

Comment: Can you please add some data in the text form?

Comment: @Grayrigel   Can I put a picture of it instead ?

Comment: might be easier if you turned your textual date into an actual datetime - and your conditions could be rephrased as `if month in "01 02 03":` or `if month in ("01","02","03"):` (use ( or [..] or {..}

Comment: @meerakapoor It is not possible for us to copy/paste and reproduce the error from the picture. You don't have to add full data. Just add some sample data.

Comment: you can do `df.head().to_csv("tata.csv")` to get some demo data to post here

Comment: @PatrickArtner  have have edited my question to include how the grouped data looks like, please check

Comment: it's a very weird way to use groupby, can you show how the dataframe ```city``` looks like

Comment: @StupidWolf Does the picture that I have added to my question do the job ?

Comment: Yeah.. ok you have some variables that are not numeric.. I wrote something below..maybe will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to groupby the columns with values, and perform the operations.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Region':[1,2,3],'City':['a','b','c'],'Country':['A','B','C']})

df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1,(3,12)),
columns=['2000-01','2000-02','2000-03','2000-04','2000-05','2000-06','2001-01','2001-02','2001-03','2001-04','2001-05','2001-06'])],axis=1)
```

You can use the date time function to create quarters:

```
def quarter(val):
    return pd.to_datetime(val).to_period("Q")

quarter(df.columns[3:])
 
PeriodIndex(['2000Q1', '2000Q1', '2000Q1', '2000Q2', '2000Q2', '2000Q2',
             '2001Q1', '2001Q1', '2001Q1', '2001Q2', '2001Q2', '2001Q2'],
            dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')
```

Then we take columns that have the numerical values:

```
df.iloc[:,3:].groupby(quarter,axis=1).mean()
 
     2000Q1    2000Q2    2001Q1    2001Q2
0  0.506088  0.438958  0.132090  0.360160
1  0.635036  0.496895  0.673494  0.437333
2  0.560944  0.640423  0.603011  0.482962
```

You can always concat back the first three columns:

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:3],df.iloc[:,3:].groupby(quarter,axis=1).mean()],axis=1)
```